# Inserting key/Value pairs at the end of a nested array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I need to create a nested array using a recursive function.  My sticking point is figuring out the correct key value when I insert something new.

The array would be empty initially and should look something like this after a few recursive calls.

```
[Family]
   [0]
      [Name]...
   [1]
      [Name]...
      [Family]
         [0]
            [Name]...
            [Family]
               [0]
                  [Name]....
```

Each call to the recursive function creates one [Family] key along with its subsidiary [Name'] key (there are other keys of [Family] too, just keeping it to one for simplicity).  That has to be inserted immediately after the last [Name] key in the array at whatever depth that happens to be at the time.

The input data is a GEDCOM file, a standard way of representing family keys in a simple text file format.  My code to create a single [Family] key form the GEDCOM file works fine but I cannot figure out how to add each ['Family] key to the end of the the output array in each recursive call.

For example, after the first call to the recursive function, the array should look like this:

```
[Family]
   [0]
      [Name]...
   [1]
      [Name]...
```

The [Family] Key created by the recursive function would look like this:

```
[Family]
         [0]
            [Name]...
```

It should be inserted into the array after [Family][1][Name].

The problem I have is that I do not know the structure of the array at the time I need to append each [Family] key since the array is updated on each call to the recursive function, and there is an unknown number of dimensions in the array.

Pete

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far, and where you're stuck specifically?

Comment: Please show your actual structures, with data types and expected i/o.